# Azure as a dumb hosting for several sites?

Tags: azure, hosting

I have several web sites with very low requirements for the server (mostly no DBs, few visitors).

I am certain an extra small instance on Azure will meet my computational needs. The cost seems to be competitive too.

Actually these sites don't need the Azure architecture. The reason I am looking at it is that I have it to play with.

One option I saw is deploying a VM, but it seems a bit too involved for my liking.

Is there another option? And is what I am trying to do reasonable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Windows Azure Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8396), where you'll see a lab for creating multiple sites within a Web Role. Unless you have something very esoteric where the install can't be automated or completed within a very short timespan, you have no reason to use a VM Role.

I answered a similar question about multiple sites within an Extra Small instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203744/windows-azure-can-i-run-multiple-websites-on-the-same-extra-small-instance-or-sma/7204315#7204315).

One other thought is to store static content (jpg's, etc.) in blob storage, as this will remove load from your Web role instances, and also let you update your content without pushing out a new deployment.

Answer (score 3):

You should use Windows Azure Accelerator for Web Roles (http://waawebroles.codeplex.com/). Its exactly what your looking for :)

Comment: Project has discontinued since latest release of Azure