# Multiple deploys on single azure instance

Tags: deployment, azure, msdeploy

I have a question regarding azure deploys. My specific scenario is that I would like to deploy N projects on the same WebRole / WebSite.

The solution (don't think only as a visual studio way of organizing projects) will involve 1 web service (that could be scaled-out later) and N web sites (that also could be scaled-out later)

Because right now my traffic is very low I was planning to deploy the web app on port 80 (of course) and the web services on say port 5000 of the same instance to save some money.

What i can't figure out right now is how to do this... in the end i have 2 questions:
-1: Can I deploy multiple projects in a single instance? ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343519/multiple-roles-on-the-same-instance-in-windows-azure) is similar but is not straighfoward... I was hoping for a more direct answer...)
-2: How?

EDIT: Don't get this question wrong! I do not want to create a azure web role project in VS 2012 and "Add" the 2 minor projects... i want to create 2 projects completaly independent... 2 separated solutions... separated deploys (ex: I want to correct a bug in the service without updating the web-site!)

Am I being clear? if not just say and I will re-explain...

Comment: -1. This question can be answered just by googling. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/gg433110.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Azure Can I run multiple WebSites on the same Extra small instance or Small instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203744/windows-azure-can-i-run-multiple-websites-on-the-same-extra-small-instance-or-sm)

Comment: @JcFx, David Makogon you got my question wrong! I futher edited it!

Comment: Will these 2 projects have the same base URL? Or will there be 2 distinct URLs? If there are 2 separate URLs then you have 2 separate sites and should host them as such

Comment: @levelnis i don't think thats true because i could use host headers... but yes they can have the same URL... let's say its http://mywebapp.com and http://mywebapp.com:5000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the edits to your question, the short answer is no, you can't have two completely different solutions that deploy to the same instance without overwriting the other.  For Azure one role is the smallest unit of deployment.

You might be able to write your own auto updating code, but you'd be on your own there, there's nothing baked into the service to help you with this.